# How to set column width to autofit in Kendo Grid MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

> I use to my page of Kendo grid that have multi columns.
>   I want set a column width to autofit and change width automatically.
>   Plz help me , thanks

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<GardeshKar.Models.v_marhaleh_marahel>()
    .Name("grdMarahel_Gardeshkar")
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Custom().Name("btnAddMarhaleh").Text("اضافه").HtmlAttributes(new { id = "btnAddMarhaleh", href = "#" }))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Code).Width(50).Title("کد");
        columns.Bound(c => c.Desc).Width(150).Title("شرح");//Autofit
        columns.Command(c => c.Destroy().Text("حذف")).Width(70).Title("عملیات");
    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 380px;" })
    .Scrollable()
    .Sortable()
    .Resizable(rl => rl.Columns(true))
    .Selectable(sl => sl.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single).Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(m => m.Id(p => p.id))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Get_DS_Marahel_Gardeshkar", "Home",
                    new { intGardesh = ViewBag.CodeGardeshKar }))
        .Destroy(del => del.Action("Del_Marhaleh_GardeshKar", "Home")))
)
```

> that column specific with autofit must column width change to autofit

Comment: Have you tried removing the Width assignment from the Column ?

Comment: Make sure that the element where Grid is declared is not restricted by width via any style.

Comment: no use style for this grid or columns

Comment: Remove scrollable then it will set to autofit. Kendo Grid does not allow autoset width with scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to remove the "Scrollable" property or you can use this function in dataBound event.

```
        function Autocolumnwidth(e) {
            var grid = e.sender;
            for (var i = 0; i < grid.columns.length; i++) {
                 grid.autoFitColumn(i);
            }
        }
```