# Kendo UI MVC4 Grid Column Header is not aligned with data

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, alignment, kendo-grid

I am using kendo UI MVC4 helper. I have already set fixed width for each column, but when loading the data the data and header are not aligned. Then, when re-sizing any column, all the columns will aligned properly(No issue). Please let me know any solution to be aigned while loading the content. And am using grouping also.

Please check the screen shot.

Just After Load data

[image]

After re-sizing any column
[image]

Please check my html helper part.

```
.....
.Columns(columns =>
                 {
                     columns.Bound(p => p.EvaluationDT_ID).Hidden(true);
                     columns.Bound(p => p.ItemID).Hidden(true);
                     columns.Bound(p => p.ItemName).Width("160px").HtmlAttributes(new { title = "#= ItemName #" }).Sortable(true);
                     columns.Bound(p => p.Itemcode).Width("80px");
                     columns.Bound(p => p.Brand).Width("90px").HtmlAttributes(new { title = "#= Brand #" });
                     columns.Bound(p => p.Weight).Width("50px").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: right" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:left;" });
                     columns.Bound(p => p.UOMCode).Width("50px");
                     columns.Bound(p => p.PackagingName).Width("50px");
......
```

Comment: Please see the solutions mentioned for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535967/how-to-set-column-width-to-autofit-in-kendo-grid-mvc

Comment: Thanks Amal, There is no solid answer for above question, even I have tried all mentioned in the discussion, but not working.

Comment: Because of grouping columns, there will scroll bar come in kedno grid body and that take space.I have same problem, so may be scroll bar coming is your problem.

Comment: Yes. scroll bar already there. bcz I have more column. Is there any solution in css/jquery to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try answer from this blog. May be helpfull.

http://blog.falafel.com/kendo-grid-hierarchy-shared-column-headers/

Comment: My requirement is different.